# Bootstrap doesn`t work without internet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I begin to use Bootstrap. And I add `js/bootstrap.min.css`
to my `index.html` and all works.

But, when I add `bootstrap.min.js` to `index.html` ,my, for example, dropdown menu doesn't work.

But, when I add `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` - my dropdown menu works.

I want to work with menu without connecting to Internet.
Why?

Comment: Yes. I have folder js,and in this include my bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery in order to work.  Download jQuery as well, and put that in the js folder, exactly the same as you did with Bootstrap, and then include it in the html file.

Comment: you have include bootstrap.min.css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should download the script at your local system and put the script at in your project JS OR Script folder and call it from there.

like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

hopefully it works :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
```

JQuery:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp
```

Download and link the files correctly via relative paths.

Comment: Please don't recommend W3Schools. Their information is at best outdated and at worst completely wrong or misguided. For jQuery, the best resource is the documentation: http://api.jquery.com or the getting started guide: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are you suggesting "Both versions can be downloaded from jQuery.com." is incorrect, and the examples of linking via downloaded links is not substantial for new programmers? Because i would disagree completely.

Comment: I'm saying that W3Schools are a group of liars who pretend to be affiliated with the W3C to gain some validity whilst spreading incorrect information about the subjects they purportedly are experts in. I wouldn't give them any traffic at all. In this case I would avoid them completely and link directly to jQuery.com.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses `jquery`, since your need to use it without internet download the jquery file and put it inside JS folder and serve it to `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

1) You are using jQuery library but not  bootstrap

2) if you want to download bootstrap library to local, you will get from here : [enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cdn path in your index.html like this

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Latest JQuery CDN Link -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
```

try using relative path after downloading the required files as below:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Latest JQuery CDN Link -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

In your case `jquery-latest.js` must be downloaded from given link and included in index.html using relative path.